# Which is the best way to label a csv file for being converted into json file in python

Tags: python, json, csv, nested

I want to create a .csv template for those that does not know .json format. However I am not sure which is the best way to label nested attributes and lists from json. For example this:

```
[
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 46,
    address: [
       {
        street:"longroad",
        number: 12,
        type: "main adress"
       },
       {
        street:"summerroad",
        number: 25,
        type: "summer house"
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

I was thinking about:

```
name,age,address/street-1,address/number-1,address/street-2,address/number-2
```

or

```
name,age,address.street-1,address.number-1,address.street-2,address.number-2
```

So what do you think? I personally don't like it... I am trying to get the easiest one for being converted in python (from .csv to .json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to embed a CSV within a CSV. The idea would be to use comma as separators for the file, and then a semicolon separator for the fields that have multiple values:

```
 csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

and then for each column that contains embedded values:

```
 for line in csv_data:
      if ';' in line:
          csv_embed_data = csv.reader([line], delimiter=';')
      # continue parsing
```

then your CSV would look like:

```
name,age,street;number
John,46,longroad;12
```

For a list of value with same `(name,age)` then you'd want to repeat the rows for each different values:

```
name,age,street;number;type
John,46,longroad;12;"main address"
John,46,summerroad;12;"summer house"
```

HTH

Comment: I like the idea of the embed CSV, thank you very much. What I don't see is the part of repeating rows for the same person just because it has different address. Because the idea would ideally be to have a row per person.

Comment: Well, the issue is that you lack expressivity in CSV. Basically, a CSV is 2 dimensions, and nesting is like having a third dimension, and having a list of addresses a fourth. So whatever you choose is not going to be a good solution, merely a hack.

Comment: Thevreal good solution would to provide your users with an editor tailored to your data that produces the right kind of json. Or use XML, and use a plist like looking editor